# Get current process status for the whole events

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

Current status with events under the same id

I have tried to add up the status by eval case (could manage only one event )not all events under the same process.

```
|eval Status = case (eventId="endProcess"  ,"Completed" ,eventId="error","Terminated") 
|stats earliest(when) AS startTime latest(when) AS endTime by mainprocessname ,resourceName , Status 
|eval startTime = strftime( strptime( startTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7NZ"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
|eval endTime = strftime( strptime( endTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7NZ"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

|table startTime, endTime , mainprocessname,resourceName, Status
```

my result now

```
startTime   endTime    mainprocessname  resourceName       Status
2019-08-16 06:15:16 2019-08-16 06:15:16 03 - SSam Scott    Completed
```

what I want to get the different time  (but I get exact same time because it is grouped by status over event ) any tip to get the Status for the whole process

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest Status, don't group by Status.  Replace the `stats` command with this one:

```
|stats earliest(when) AS startTime latest(when) AS endTime latest(Status) as Status by mainprocessname ,resourceName
```